# how to postpone instructions in a method in android programming

Tags: java, android, wait

I would to postpone a set of java istructions in onStart() Method,for example,if I have this source:

```
int turn=1;

public void onStart(){

if(turn==1){
/* do something */
turn=2
}

if(turn=2){
/* wait 5 seconds and do something */
turn=1;
}
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Use handler.postDelayed()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
}, 5000);
```